# VBA Rename file after FTP: permission denied

Tags: ms-access, permissions, vba, filesystemobject

I have a piece of code which sftp's down a file. I then read the log to test if it has completed. I then test the file to see if it's size is bigger than 0kb. Once those steps are complete I then attempt to rename the file using filesystemobject. Extracts of the code below:

```
'Wait for FTP to complete
Do While Not (bSFTPDownloadComplete(strLogFile))
    Sleep 2000
Loop

'Wait for file to not be 0KB
Do Until FileSize(strFile) > 0
    Sleep 2000
Loop

'Move file to filename
RenameFile strFile, strNewFile
```

---

`bSFTPDownloadComplete` is reading the contents and testing for "Total downloaded files:  1" (I'm only ever downloading 1 file at a time here) and this works fine, I can go into more detail if required but I really don't think this is the problem.

---

**FileSize** is as follows:

```
Function FileSize(strPath As String) As Double
Dim fso As FileSystemObject

FileSize = 0

Set fso = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")

If fso.FileExists(strPath) Then
    FileSize = fso.GetFile(strPath).size
End If

Set fso = Nothing
End Function
```

---

**RenameFile** is as follows:

```
Function RenameFile(strOrig As String, strNew As String)
Dim fso As FileSystemObject

Set fso = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")

fso.MoveFile strOrig, strNew

Set fso = Nothing
End Function
```

---

On very large files I get a Run-Time 70 Permission Denied error on the `fso.MoveFile` line. It has successfully passed the test that the ftp log says it has completed and the size of the file is bigger than 0.

If I then wait a few seconds it invariably is fine and the code can continue. I don't really want to Sleep for a few seconds as the potential for even larger files will means it will still break and I just waste time.

Is there a way for me to test if the file is still being used by another process? If not the only way I can see going forward is for me to put an error handler in the function that sleeps and resumes if the err = 70 but this doesn't seem ideal in my head.

Any ideas would be gratefully received.

Comment: What are you using to actually download the file? Have you checked the permissions of the actual file yet?

Comment: I'm using CoreFTP via Shell command. It goes `strFTP="C:\Program Files\CoreFTP\coreftp.exe -s -delsrc -log C:\Temp\ftplog.txt -O -d sftp://user:pwd@server:port/filepath -p C:\temp\"` (I've substituted some bits out of that string) and then `VBA.Shell strFTP, vbMinimizedNoFocus`.

Comment: From their website: "In build 1437, a utility called corecmd.exe was added to allow blocking transfers. Use the same commmand line parameters your transfers will block until completed."  Are you using a blocking transfer or an asynchronous one?

Comment: It'll be asynchronous as it's that for coreftp. I guess I could try using corecmd and seeing if that works...

Comment: My last comment wasn't exactly clear - corecmd.exe should be part of recent CoreFTP installs.  I'd check to see if you already have it.

Comment: I don't have it, I have build 1795 but it's probably because it's CoreFTP LE rather than a full version. I've no choice about it as that's what work has provided so looks like that route is unlikely.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK, I've got it. Instead of basing it on filesize, I'm checking if coreftp.exe is still open as a process:

```
'Check for coreftp.exe to close - Command line should match strFTP
Do While bCoreFTPRunning(strFTP)
    Sleep 2000
Loop
```

The function used is as follows:

```
Function bCoreFTPRunning(strFTP As String) As Boolean
Dim objWMIService, colProcessList, objProcess, i As Integer

bCoreFTPRunning = False

Set objWMIService = GetObject("winmgmts:{impersonationLevel=impersonate}!\\.\root\cimv2")

Set colProcessList = objWMIService.ExecQuery("Select * from Win32_Process Where Name = 'coreftp.exe'")

For Each objProcess In colProcessList
If Replace(objProcess.commandline, Chr(34), "") = strFTP Then
    bCoreFTPRunning = True
End If
Next

Set objWMIService = Nothing
Set colProcessList = Nothing
End Function
```

The commandline in the process is the same as what I already have in place as strFTP (apart from it has some extra double quotes).